# Associate XML Attribute with Class Property

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

I am building an MVC App in C# and am currently working on a method to load an xml document into a file stream and iterate through the nodes and save the data into my model objects.

It is all working fine but I am hard coding the relationship between the object property and the xml attribute name.  I was wondering if there is a smart way to associated the two so I can run it all through a for each loop.

This is the code I have currently and it works, but I would like to make it more generic

**OLD CODE**

```
var xmlDoc = LoadXmlFileIntoStream("WSAPayCode.xml");

                var elementCollection = ExtractDescendants(xmlDoc, "WSAPayCode");



                foreach (var element in elementCollection)
                {

                    var abbreviationChar = element.Attribute("AbbreviationChar");

                    var payCode = new PayCode
                    {
                        Name = element.Attribute("Name").Value,
                        AutoResolved = element.Attribute("AutoResolved").Value.IsBool(),
                        EditExcuseAbsn = element.Attribute("EditExcuseAbsn").Value.IsBool(),
                        PersistPceSw = element.Attribute("PersistPceSw").Value.IsBool(),
                        AbbreviationChar = (string)element.Attribute("AbbreviationChar"),
                        EditCntToCdotSw = element.Attribute("EditCntToCdotSw").Value.IsBool(),
                        EditAffShfTotal = element.Attribute("EditAffShfTotal").Value.IsBool(),
                        EditCntToOt = element.Attribute("EditCntToOt").Value.IsBool(),
                        PayUsingWeightedAverageRate = element.Attribute("PayUsingWeightedAverageRate").Value.IsBool(),
                        RequiresMgrApproval = element.Attribute("RequiresMgrApproval").Value.IsBool(),
                        WeightedAverageRateIsComputedDaily =
                            element.Attribute("WeightedAverageRateIsComputedDaily").Value.IsBool(),
                        JustAutoResExpAsWorked = element.Attribute("JustAutoResExpAsWorked").Value.IsBool(),
                        AssociatedDurationPayCodeName = element.Attribute("AssociatedDurationPayCodeName").Value,
                        WeightedAverageRateContributionsUseAnAdjustedRate =
                            element.Attribute("WeightedAverageRateContributionsUseAnAdjustedRate").Value.IsBool(),
                        ScheduleHoursType = element.Attribute("ScheduleHoursType").Value,
                        CheckAvlbltySw = element.Attribute("CheckAvlbltySw").Value.IsBool(),
                        WageAddition = (string)element.Attribute("WageAddition"),
                        VisibleInMainArea = element.Attribute("VisibleInMainArea").Value.IsBool(),
                        IsMoneyCategory = element.Attribute("IsMoneyCategory").Value.IsBool(),
                        AmountType = element.Attribute("AmountType").Value,
                        VisibleInReport = element.Attribute("VisibleInReport").Value.IsBool(),
                        ContributesToWeightedAverageRates =
                            element.Attribute("ContributesToWeightedAverageRates").Value.IsBool(),
                        UnjustAutoResExpAsWorked = (bool)element.Attribute("UnjustAutoResExpAsWorked"),
                        WageMultiply = (string)element.Attribute("WageMultiply"),
                        Type = (string)element.Attribute("Type"),
                        VisibleToUser = (bool)element.Attribute("VisibleToUser"),
                        CustomerId = _customerId,
                    };

                    _db.PayCodes.Add(payCode);
                    _db.SaveChanges();

                }
```

**New Code**
I have written some code to interate through the xml file and pull out the names of the attributes - Code Below (Also works)

```
var xmlDoc = LoadXmlFileIntoStream("WSAPayCode.xml");

                    var elementCollection = ExtractDescendants(xmlDoc, "WSAPayCode");

                    var nodeAttributes = xmlDoc.Descendants("WSAPayCode").Select(x => x.Attributes());

                    foreach (var attrs in nodeAttributes)
                    {
                        var _attribute = "";
                        foreach (var attr in attrs)
                        {
                            // This successfully reads through each attribute and pulls out the name of the attribut
                            _attribute = attr.Name.ToString();
                        }

                    }
```

**Problem I would like to solve**

What I would like to do now is instantiate an object and iterate through the attribute names and save the values to the corresponding property in the object. i.e. replace the OLD code with something that dynamically assigns the values to the object properties.

Comment: Are you creating the XML document yourself?  Have you looked at the Xml Serializers/Deserializers which can handle a lot of this for you?

Comment: I am actually reading from a 3rd party xml to populate the objects in my database.  I am loading it through filestream

Answer (score 0):

I would check into using the XML Serializers / Deserializers.  On your class, you have provide attributes as to whether the property is an element or attribute, and then let it handle the rest of it for you.

You could set the attributes to match what the XML document is providing, such as if the name is an element, or attribute, etc.

For example:

```
[XmlRoot("PayCode")]
public class PayCode
{
    [XmlElement("Name")
    public string Name { get; set;}

    ....
}
```

Then, to deserialize to your object:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new
XmlSerializer(typeof(PayCode));

FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fs);

PayCode payCode = (PayCode)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Comment: Thanks - I am not sure how that helps me associate each attribute to each property.